# "pilot.validation.istio.io" fails on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio

I enabled Istio on GKE using istio-addon. According to the images the version of Istio is `1.6`. Deployment of the application, which contains `RequestAuthentication` resource gives the following error:

```
 admission webhook "pilot.validation.istio.io" denied the request:
 unrecognized type RequestAuthentication
```

`RequestAuthentication` must be available in the version `1.6`. Is there any way to check the compatibility?

Updated: On my on-premise installation everything works with Istio `1.9`. The configuration is the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata: 
  name: xxx-auth
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xxx-fe
  jwtRules:
  - issuer:  "{{ .Values.idp.issuer }}"
    jwksUri: "{{ .Values.idp.jwksUri }}"
```

Comment: Hi there! What GKE version you are running? How you enabled the Istio GKE add on?

Comment: Istio was enabled through console. The version of GKE is 1.20.8-gke.900

Comment: Could you attach your yaml files to the question?

Comment: Did you attach your on-premise installation with istio 1.9 or your old version with 1.6?

Comment: It is the same. Istio 1.6 supports RequestAuthentication

Comment: Did you check the result with your on-premise installation with istio 1.6?

Comment: Finally, I turned off istio addon and installed the newest istio 1.11.1. It worked without any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted community wiki answer for better visibility.

As [Katya Gorshkova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9496448/katya-gorshkova) has mentioned in the comment:

> Finally, I turned off istio addon and installed the newest istio 1.11.1. It worked without any problems

See also

- [release notes for istio 1.11.1](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.11.x/announcing-1.11.1/)
- [how to upgrade istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/)
- [Important changes to consider when upgrading to Istio 1.11.0](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.11.x/announcing-1.11/upgrade-notes/)